# Should one avoid deriving benefit from miracles?

Tags: sources-mekorot, miracle, masechet-taanis

In [Taanit 24b](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.24b.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) it states

> אֲמַר רַב מָרִי בְּרַהּ דְּבַת שְׁמוּאֵל: אֲנָא הֲוָה קָאֵימְנָא אַגּוּדָּא דִּנְהַר פָּפָּא, חֲזַאי לְמַלְאֲכֵי דְּאִידְּמוֹ לְמַלָּחֵי דְּקָא מַיְיתִי חָלָא וּמְלוֹנְהוּ לְאַרְבֵּי, וַהֲוָה קִמְחָא דִּסְמִידָא. אֲתוֹ כּוּלֵּי עָלְמָא לְמִיזְבַּן, אָמֵינָא לְהוּ: מֵהָא לָא תִּיזְבְּנוּן דְּמַעֲשֵׂה נִסִּים הוּא, לִמְחַר אָתְיָין אַרְבֵי דְּחִיטֵּי דְּפַרְזִינָא.

> Rav Mari, son of Shmuel’s daughter, said: At that moment, I was standing on the bank of the Pappa River. I saw angels who appeared as sailors bringing sand and filling ships with it, and it became fine flour. Everyone came to buy this flour, but I said to them: **Do not purchase this flour, as it is the product of miracles.** Tomorrow, boats filled with wheat will come from Parzina, and you may purchase that produce.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.24b.5?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Taanit.24b.5.4&lang2=bi) there comments that it is appropriate to avoid/distance one's self from the work of miracles.
I would like to know the source for the idea of not deriving benefit from miracles since throughout Tanach it is common for people to partake in the benefit of miracles (eg the Ma'n, the kikayon of Yonah etc.).

Comment: If I have time, I will try to find sources, but it shouldn't be hard. This is a very strong principle in Torah Hashkafa, to not benefit/rely on miracles. Not relying on them is so we can preserve the purpose of free will, the whole purpose of Olam Hazeh. Not benefiting from them because it is inappropriate. We are not here to "benefit", we are here to earn (we are born without any merits at all, we deserve nothing). So, especially with regards to "miracles", benefiting from them is wholly inappropriate and gravely looked upon from Above

Comment: Is the case of Gehazi and Naaman not enough?

Comment: https://jewishvues.com/articles/praying-for-a-miracle/

Answer (score 3):

R. Ro'ey Hemed (Ro'eh baShoshanim - Hanukah, p.50) cites ten different sources addressing why the Hashmonaim were permitted to use the oil if we are not permitted to benefit from miracles (as per Taanith 24b which your query concerns). Hopefully some of these sources will shed some light on better understanding the principle.

1. According to R. Sevi Pesah Frank, that statement only applies for miracles performed לצורך האדם (for human needs) but a miracle that is performed לצורך גבוה (for Divine "need") there is no prohibition to benefit from (Miqrai Qodesh, Hanukah 7:12)
2. The Hida (Nahal Qadumim, Pareshath Beshalah) questioned how could the Israelites eat the manna, isn't it prohibited to benefit from miracles? The prohibition only applies to a miracle for an individual because the reliance on the miracle detracts from his merits, however miracles performed for the masses do not so detract and may therefore be benefited from.
3. R. Sevi Pesah Frank also quotes the Shu"T Beth She'arim (OH 238) when a miracle comes to man by means of prayer he should not rely on it, however the Hanukah miracle was different, they did not pray for the oil it simply came to them "derekh nissim" (by miraculous means) and it therefore is permitted to benefit from.
4. The Bnei Yisoskhar says that the purpose of the oil was for the performance of a miswa and accordingly the principle of מצוות לאו להנות נתנו (that the benefit derived from a miswa is not deemed hanaah) therefore applies to it.
5. 'Einey Shemuel (Shabboth 21b) citing the Beth Yosef says that precise nature of the miraculous oil oil was unclear. After they put oil in the menorah the jug was still full like it was at the outset, its possible to say that at the time that they filled the oil into the menorah the the jug of oil was also miraculously filled and accordingly it is difficult to determine which oil was actually produced miraculously (that in the menorah or that in the jug). Since the principle that one shouldn't rely on miracles is derabanan and this would be a safeq derabanan, as it is unclear which oil was produced miraculously, it is permitted to benefit.
6. Shu"T Ginze Yosef (71b) answers it by resort to the case of the manna which fell for the Israelites in the desert. How could they have eaten it we are prohibited to benefit from miracles? He answers that it was apparent from the nature of the miracle that they were supposed to eat it. Similarly by the the miracle of the jug of oil, if a miracle occurred such that they would be capable of performing the miswa of lighting the menorah it was apparent from the context that they were supposed to use it.
7. R. Shelomo Kluger in Sefer ha-Haim writes that that which is prohibited to benefit from miracles is rabbinic and that in the Miqdash the they did not decree on rabbinic prohibitions. So even though they generally needed the oil to be of a variety permitted to Yisrael, and this ostensibly was prohibited to Yisrael, it is only a Torah prohibition that they were concerned for not a rabbinic prohibition.
8. The Ben-Yehoyad'a Taanith 25a explains that the reason for the principle that one should not benefit from miracles is that reliance thereon has the effect of detracting from ones merits. If that is so, could it be the case that the righteous for whom miracles occur all the time, that the miracles performed for them detract from their merit? No, there is a difference between the Shem Hawaya and Shem Eloqim. The former transcends nature and the latter operates within it. When a miracle occurs for the righteous it comes from the aspect of the Shem Hawaya and there is no distinction between natural and unnatural within it, therefore it does not need to detract from their merit when a miracle is performed for them. However for the rest of humanity, that is subject to Shem Eloqim and miracles function within the natural order, it would detract from their merits should they benefit therefrom. The Hashmonaim, the sons of Matithyahu were righteous and God acted with them by means of Shem Hawaya and accordingly they were not prohibited to benefit from the miracle.
9. One can explain based on the Ta"Z that there is a difference between a miracle and a blessing, and when an occasion has a din of berakhah it does not have a din of nes, and accordingly no prohibition on its benefit would be applicable. The prohibition only applies to a nes gamur (overt miracle). One sees the same on the occasion of Elisha and Shunamith (presumably the author refers to the miraculous multiplication of her jugs of oil).
10. Miracles were a feature of the Miqdash, as we see Abaye (Pesahim 64b) held we rely on miracles there for there they are almost like a naturalistic phenomenon, and one can offer that on this basis there was no prohibition to benefit from miracles in the Miqdash since their nature was transformed into something akin to naturalistic and therefore it was permitted to benefit from the miraculous oil.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the answer lies in the story of the Gemara itself. He said not to purchase the flour sourced by a miracle for flour sourced by natural means will arrive tomorrow. It is not forbidden to rely on a miracle, rather it is appropriate to avoid it when possible. The Rashi you linked to states ובמה דאפשר להתרחק ממעשה ניסים יותר טוב. “To the extent that one could distance himself from the acts of miracles, it is better.” Not forbidden, just advised. The examples from Tanach may not have had natural means as an option.

Comment: Indeed, this may be supported by the story with Rav Ilish and the daughters of Rav Nachman ([*Gittin* 45a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.45a.18?lang=bi)). Rav Nachman's daughters seemed to be righteous enough that miracles would occur for them regularly, yet they were employing those miracles in a frivolous manner and in unnecessary circumstances. The conclusion of the story clarifies that, indeed, the daughters of Rav Nachman were not righteous at all and were not truly fitting to have miracles performed for them.

Answer (score 0):

What is a miracle?  This story in the same tractate shows that either everything is a miracle or nothing is:

> One Shabbat evening, Rabbi Ḥanina ben Dosa saw that his daughter was sad. He said to her: My daughter, why are you sad? She said to him: I confused a vessel of vinegar for a vessel of oil and I lit the Shabbat lamp with vinegar. [Soon the lamp will be extinguished and we will be left in the dark.] He said to her: My daughter, what are you concerned about? He Who said to the oil that it should burn can say to the vinegar that it should burn. A tanna taught: That lamp burned continuously the entire day, until they brought from it light for havdalah. [Taanit 25a]

Comment: That's a dubious takeaway, and I don't see how it answers the question.

Comment: I kinda see an answer. I was wondering about this too: If everything is a miracle, why distance oneself from miracles? But maybe we distinguish between the ones that are outside the laws of nature.